# Stream groupingBy by one field then merge all others

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have trouble with stream groupingby.

```
List<FAR> listFar = farList.stream().filter(f -> !f.getStatus().equals(ENUM.STATUS.DELETED))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<HAUL> haulList = listFar.stream().map(f -> f.getHaul()).flatMap(f -> f.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It groups by specie, it's all fine, but there are another attributes to HAUL.

```
Map<Specie, List<HAUL>> collect = haulList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(HAUL::getSpecie));
```

Attributes:

1. `haul.getFishCount();` (Integer)
2. `haul.getFishWeight();` (BigDecimal)

Is it possible to group by `HAUL::getSpecie` (by Specie), but also "merging" together those two extra fields, so I have total?

**For example:** I have 3 of HAUL elements where fish specie A has 50/30/10 kg in weight.

Can I *group it by specie* and have total weight?

Comment: u mean add those together? `getFishWeight` and `getFishCount`? or a separate sum for each?

Comment: Group by specie and then get HAUL object with getFishCount() and getFishWeight() - so those two fields have total sum of each specie (because they're grouped).

Comment: In general - seperate fields for each grouped specie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

```
haulsList 
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(HAUL::getSpecie, 
              Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                  list -> {
                     int left = list.stream().mapToInt(HAUL::getFishCount).sum();
                     BigDecimal right = list.stream().map(HAUL::getFishWeight).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (x, y) -> x.add(y));
                    return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(left, right);
                  })));
```

There is a form to do:

```
.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(HAUL::getSpecie, 
              Collectors.summingInt(HAUL::getFishCount)));
```

or

```
 .stream()
 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(HAUL::getSpecie,
             Collectors.mapping(HAUL::getFishWeight, Collectors.reducing((x, y) -> x.add(y)))));
```

But you can't really make these to act at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

You might use `mapping` and `reduce` for example:

```
class Foo {   int count;   double weight;   String spice; } 
List<Foo> fooList = Arrays.asList(
    new Foo(1,new BigDecimal(10), "a"),
    new Foo(2,new BigDecimal(38), "a"),
    new Foo(5,new BigDecimal(2), "b"),
    new Foo(4,new BigDecimal(8), "b"));

Map<String,Optional<BigDecimal>> spieceWithTotalWeight = fooList.stream().
        collect(
                groupingBy(
                        Foo::getSpice,
                        mapping(
                                Foo::getWeight, 
                                Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal::add)
                        )
                )
        );
System.out.println(spieceWithTotalWeight); // {a=Optional[48], b=Optional[10]}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have Integer (count) and BigDecimal as weight.
What do you meant by summarizingDouble?

Comment: @Kefirchiks, I have updated my answer. I was thinking that weight has a double type. I am sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm getting your question correctly, you want the total sum of `count * weight` for each specie.

You can do this by using `Collectors.groupingBy` with a downstream collector that reduces the list of `HAUL` of each specie to the sum of `haul.getFishCount() * haul.getFishWeight()`:

```
Map<Specie, BigDecimal> result = haulList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(haul -> haul.getSpecie(),
        Collectors.mapping(haul -> 
                new BigDecimal(haul.getFishCount()).multiply(haul.getFishWeight()), 
            Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal::plus))));
```

This will get the total sum of `count * weight` for each specie. If you could add the following method to your `Haul` class:

```
public BigDecimal getTotalWeight() {
    return new BigDecimal(getFishCount()).multiply(getFishWeight());
}
```

Then, collecting the stream would be easier and more readable:

```
Map<Specie, BigDecimal> result = haulList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(haul -> haul.getSpecie(),
        Collectors.mapping(haul -> haul.getTotalWeight(), 
            Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal::plus))));
```

---

**EDIT:** After all, it seems that you want separate sums for each field...

I would use `Collectors.toMap` with a merge function for this. Here's the code:

```
Map<Specie, List<BigDecimal>> result = haulList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        haul -> haul.getSpecie(),
        haul -> Arrays.asList(
            new BigDecimal(haul.getFishCount()), 
            haul.getFishWeight()),
        (list1, list2) -> {
            list1.set(0, list1.get(0).plus(list2.get(0)));
            list1.set(1, list1.get(1).plus(list2.get(1)));
            return list1;
        }));
```

This uses a list of 2 elements to store the fish count at index `0` and the fish weight at index `1`, for every specie.

Comment: Works for multiplying purpose. But I just wanted to group and then get total sum of separate elements.

Comment: @Kefirchiks I've updated the answer to show summing two separate fields.